# Se pierde variable std::string en constructor

Tags: c++, poo

Tengo una clase con varios 5 constructores, pero hay uno en que se pierde el  valor de la variable entregada para la creacion del objeto. Al hacer el unit test este me muestra que el atributo dentro de la clase es `'\x1'`, cunado debería ser un `std::string`, o `false` cuando debería ser `true`.

La clase la tengo definida de la siguiente forma:

```cpp
class Regla {

    private:

    protected:
        std::string __regla;
        std::string __mensaje;
        bool __estado = false;
        bool __partida = false;
        unsigned char __contador = 0;

    public:
        Regla() {}; //ok
        Regla(const std::string regla); //ok
        Regla(const std::string regla, const bool reglaDePartida); //ok
        Regla(const std::string regla, const std::string mensaje); //ok
        Regla(const std::string regla, const std::string mensaje, const bool reglaDePartida); //error

}

Regla::Regla (const std::string regla) {
    this->__regla = regla;
}

Regla::Regla (const std::string regla, const bool reglaDePartida) {
    this->__regla = regla;
    this->__partida = reglaDePartida;
}

Regla::Regla(const std::string regla, const std::string mensaje) {
    this->__regla = regla;
    this->__mensaje = mensaje;
}

Regla::Regla(const std::string regla, const std::string mensaje, const bool reglaDePartida) {
    this->__regla = regla;
    this->__mensaje = mensaje;
    this->__regla = reglaDePartida;
}
```

Todos los constructores pasan el unit test menos el ultimo, al que se le pasan 3 variables. Para confirmar que no era un problema del test, genere el mismo caso en la función main y me dio los mismos resultados.

Este es el código del test, lo estoy haciendo con google test framework.

```cpp
#include "../../include/Regla.hpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class ReglaTest2 : public ::testing::Test{
    protected:
        Regla *r;
        const std::string sRegla = "Regla";
        const std::string sMensaje = "Mensaje";
        const bool bPartida = true;

    public:
        void SetUp() {
            r = new Regla(sRegla, sMensaje, bPartida);
        }

        void TearDown(){
            delete r;
        }
};

TEST_F(ReglaTest2, tReglaCtorARglAMsjAPrtd) {
    EXPECT_EQ("Regla", r->getRegla());
    EXPECT_EQ("Mensaje", r->getMensaje());
    EXPECT_FALSE(r->getEstado());
    EXPECT_TRUE(r->getReglaDePartida());
    EXPECT_EQ(0, r->getContador());
};
```

Al compilar y ejecutar esto, me da como resultado:

```
[ RUN      ] ReglaTest2.tReglaCtorARglAMsjAPrtd
src/Regla_Test.cpp:50: Failure
      Expected: "Regla"
To be equal to: r->getRegla()
      Which is: "\x1"
src/Regla_Test.cpp:53: Failure
Value of: r->getReglaDePartida()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] ReglaTest2.tReglaCtorARglAMsjAPrtd (0 ms)
```

Por ultimo, en la función main hice lo siguiente:

```
#include "../include/Regla.hpp"

int main() {

  Regla *r = new Regla(sRegla, sMensaje, bPartida);
  std::cout << "se creo el primer objeto" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "La variable Regla es: " << sRegla << std::endl;
  std::cout << "La variable Mensaje es: " << sMensaje << std::endl;
  std::cout << "la variable partida es: " << bPartida << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  Regla r1(sRegla, sMensaje, bPartida);
  std::cout << "se creo el segundo objeto" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "La variable Regla es: " << sRegla << std::endl;
  std::cout << "La variable Mensaje es: " << sMensaje << std::endl;
  std::cout << "la variable partida es: " << bPartida << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "TEST 1: " << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "Regla: " << r->getRegla() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "Mensaje: " << r->getMensaje() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Partida?: " << r->getReglaDePartida() << std::endl << std::endl;


  std::cout << "TEST 2:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Regla: " << r1.getRegla() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Mensaje: " << r1.getMensaje() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Partida?: " << r1.getReglaDePartida() << bPartida << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Lo que salida me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
./bin/main
se creo el primer objeto
la variable Regla es: Regla
la variable Mensaje es: Mensaje
la variable partida es: 1

se creo el segundo objeto
la variable Regla es: Regla
la variable Mensaje es: Mensaje
la variable partida es: 1

TEST 1: 
Regla: 
Mensaje: Mensaje
Partida?: 0

TEST 2:
Regla: 
Mensaje: Mensaje
Partida?: 01
```

No se si estoy haciendo algo mal, he estado investigando pero no he encontrado algún caso parecido para poder revisar y saber si tengo algo mal programado.

Estoy usando ubuntu y compilardor `cpp (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`

Estaría muy agradecido de su ayuda! Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver el error es muy simple, en el último constructor le estás asignando una variable de tipo bool a una variable de tipo string.

```
Regla::Regla(const std::string regla, const std::string mensaje, const bool reglaDePartida) {
    this->__regla = regla;
    this->__mensaje = mensaje;
    this->__regla = reglaDePartida;
}
```

Debería ser `this->__partida = reglaDePartida;` en lugar de `this->__regla = reglaDePartida;` en la última inicialización.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de [Name Not Found](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/308372/2742) es correcta (¡bien visto! a mi me había pasado desapercibido) pero incompleta.

---

Es cierto que en la expresión `this->__regla = reglaDePartida;` estás asignando un booleano (`bool reglaDePartida`) a una cadena (`std::string Regla::__regla`) pero ¿cómo es esto posible? ¿no deberían ser ambos tipos incompatibles? Vamos a consultar el [operador de asignación de `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D):

> #### `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::operator=`
>
> 1. `basic_string& operator=( const basic_string& str );`
> 2. `basic_string& operator=( basic_string&& str ) noexcept(/* … */);`
> 3. `basic_string& operator=( const CharT* s );`
> 4. `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );`
> 5. `basic_string& operator=( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist );`
> 6. `template<class T> basic_string& operator=( const T& t );`

Dado que estás usando `std::string` sabemos que `CharT` es `char`, así que la sexta la única sobrecarga por la que podría haber sido asignado un `bool`, pero la documentación indica (traducción y resaltado míos):

> 6. Implícitamente convierte `t` a `string_view` como si se hubiese llamado `std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> sv = t;`, tras lo cual reemplaza el contenido con el contenido de `sv` como si se hubiera llamado `assign(sv)`. Esta sobrecarga sólo se tiene en cuenta si `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` es verdadero y `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, const CharT*>` es falso.

Vamos a [comprobar](https://tio.run/##nY7NCsIwEITP5imWFrT@gXjU2ptPoIcehBK3aV2oSUm2goivboyKiEc97GF2duZbbNtpjeh9TBqbrlSQknFslTxm4rPjc6sKtpLYZULEpapIK9iuN9skH0KcQwSrMGkKuRCkGY6SdDIUF9FzXC4WaDp@uNFTkSvQ6JOyTPtGFac0KMewN6bpT@B5El4gXWfv1l9jITLY6cHyD/xL4EHa0S/4r9gHbxV3VsNsKa7e37BqZO38NPStcDyeyzs) si se ha dado el caso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::is_convertible_v<const bool&, std::string> = " << std::is_convertible_v<const bool&, std::string> << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::is_convertible_v<const bool&, const char*> = " << std::is_convertible_v<const bool&, const char*> << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> std::is_convertible_v<const bool&, std::string> = 0
> std::is_convertible_v<const bool&, const char*> = 0
> ```

Lo que indica que la sexta sobrecarga **no** ha sido escogida. Entonces ¿Cómo se ha asignado un booleano a un `std::string`? Para averiguarlo, vamos a imitar esa clase y la llenamos de chivatos:

```
#include <iostream>

struct string_falso
{
    string_falso& operator=( const string_falso& str )
    { std::cout << 1 << '\n'; return *this; }

    string_falso& operator=( string_falso&& str ) noexcept(true)
    { std::cout << 2 << '\n'; return *this; }

    string_falso& operator=( const char* s )
    { std::cout << 3 << '\n'; return *this; }

    string_falso& operator=( char ch )
    { std::cout << 4 << '\n'; return *this; }

    string_falso& operator=( std::initializer_list<char> ilist )
    { std::cout << 5 << '\n'; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    string_falso a, b;

    a = b;
    a = string_falso{};
    a = nullptr;
    a = 'X';
    a = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};

    return 0;
}
```

El [código anterior](https://tio.run/##nVFNS8QwED03v2JA2HS/QFe9bNsFDx48eRI8CEuczXYHsklJUhBL/7o10Qq7Fj308uZNMrz3JsGqWpaIXXdBGlW9k5CTcd5KcdwwFkiNHkIhXW73QjnDGpac9hMwlbTCG1ukgEa78/FJ7GAKTai79RpN7SHP4SoCf9E8Ayt9bTXM/IFcBu0/6mcXP8LayDeUlU9DVDnwWY3x@d4CD8LOwA2zX4/SDGoBhmo3414iKJAmT0LRu7RbRc7n0WMDFPnQ5/ZvnzZjjLSHoyCdTn9/MIgFvIaJREARyVc9HWja/lDXSlXe9h1/5j1r@B1fAL@P8BDhMcITj75JH@YyY23XfeBeidJ1yxC9wPl8JT4B) produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```

Y si lo cambiamos a esto:

```
int main()
{
    string_falso s;

    s = true;
    s = false;

    return 0;
}
```

Muestra:

> ```
> 4
> 4
> ```

Por lo tanto, asignar un booleano a un `std::string` invoca la cuarta sobrecarga del operador de asignación ¿Por qué?.

En C++ los caracteres son tipos numéricos, cuando en una expresión encontramos un tipo numérico los operandos son transformados a un tipo común (esto se conoce como promoción de tipos). En este caso `bool` (también un tipo numérico) se promociona a `char` y acto seguido se asigna a `std::string`.

Cuando un booleano se promociona a entero, obtiene cero cuando es falso y uno cuando es verdadero, ese es el `'\x1'` que obtienes.